# get list of places from Foursquare like Facebook places and Google places

Tags: iphone, foursquare

I have to show a list of nearby stores, hospitals, cinemas and all according the user's latest location. I have done this thing using Facebook and Google APIs,
like this:

- Google: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=2414.016&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY
- Facebook: https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=%f,%f&distance=1000&acces_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

How can I achieve the same thing in Foursquare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by following link

```
 http://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues?geolat=yourlatitudevalue&geolong=yourlongitudevalue&q=yourkeyword.
 for example restaurant keyword
 http://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues?geolat=23.0081171&geolong=72.5234406&q=restaurant
```

You can find samples for API under following link.

```
 https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/samples.html
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know this is late.i am using :-http://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues?geolat=23.0081171&geolong=72.5234406&q=restaurant
But i m not getting the proper result..Please help em out